# Can't list data in Table View

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, cell, nsdictionary

I can print all data but I can't list in the table view. 
I search for all activity which owner is user.user_id 
And I want to list in the table view. 
But the table view displays nothing. 
[image]

Comment: pleasse post code as text not image

Comment: Casting `[String:Any]` to `NSDictionary` in Swift is horrible.

Comment: changed to (snapshot.value as? NSDictionary) still no work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reload data

```
         query. observeSingleEvent(.value, with: { [weak self] snapshot in 
            let result = snapshot.value as [String:Any]
            self?.MyAct.append(result as? NSDictionary?)

             DispatchQueue.main.async {
             self?.tableView.reloadData ()
             }

            })
```

Comment: The table view still displays nothing. And I can't append result in MyAct[String:Any]

Comment: please check it now ... hopefully resolve your issue

Comment: I tried add self.myActTableView.reloadData() but still not work.

Comment: are you doing it on main thread ?

Comment: check MyAct count ?

Comment: if you reply .. we become able to solve this ..

Comment: yes. I can print MyAct and count MyAct. result = 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213652/discussion-between-jawadali-and-hiu-chung-chan).

Answer (score 0):

Below `append` line add reload to the table

```
self.myAct.append(result as! NSDictionary?)
self.myActTableView.reloadData()
```

as the request is asynchronous , also think if you really need `observeSingleEvent` instead of the costy `observe` as with it you need to clear the array before the `append` and if you didn't you will get duplicates for any small change in your data in firebase

Also in `viewDidLoad` add

```
self.myActTableView.delegate = self
self.myActTableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: Still can't display data in table view.

Comment: @HiuChungChan don't forget to add delegate and dataSource see edit

Comment: I added delegate and dataSource in viewDidLoad but still not work.

Comment: can you `print(self.MyAct.count)` after the append ? what you get ?

Comment: Yes, and the result is 1

Comment: make sure that `print(act!["act_name"] as! String`) isn't nil print it what you get ?

Comment: @HiuChungChan This is the correct answer, with my suggestion of not using NSDictionary or [String: Any] as your result because it will loose ordering. You're better off adding the results into an array from the Snapshot `let childNodes = snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]' which will maintain their order and then iterate over that array to add each child node to your dataSource.